# custom attribute in customer address grid

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, customer-address, customer-grid, customer-address-attribute

I am trying to add a column in the customer address grid in admin with a custom attribute.

```
 <column name="addresstypes" class="xxx\AddressAttribute\Ui\Component\Listing\Address\Column\Addresstype" sortOrder="95">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Address Type</label>
            <editor>
                <editorType>text</editorType>
            </editor>
        </settings>
    </column>
```

It is added also and shown in the grid. but, the value which I in form, it's showing correctly if the customer has only one address. if they have multiple addresses, then also shows the same value for all. but in form, there is a different value.

this is my UI-component code:

```
 public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
{


    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            $name = $this->getData('name');
            if (isset($item['entity_id'])) {
                $customerId = $item['parent_id'];

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($customerId);

               $billingAddressId = $customerObj->getDefaultBilling();

                $customerAddress = array();
        foreach ($customerObj->getAddresses() as $address)
        {
            $customerAddress[] = $address->toArray();
           
        }

        foreach ($customerAddress as $customerAddres) {

            $addressId = $customerAddres['entity_id'];
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $addressshipto = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory')->create()->load($addressId);

            $addresst = $addressshipto->getData('addresstype');

             if(isset($customerAddres['addresstype'])){
            
            $addressType = $customerAddres['addresstype'];
            }   
            
            if(isset($addressType) && $addressType == 21764) {

                $item['addresstypes'] = "Bill to  ";
               }else{
                $item['addresstypes'] = "Ship to  ";
               }

         }
       
        }
    }
}
    

    return $dataSource;
}
```